# Rotate functions in "Rectangles, Ovals Digitizing" as well as "Advanced Digitizing" distort shape dimensions

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

I am trying to rotate squares via the rotate tool in the "Rectangles Ovals Digitizing" Plugin in QGIS. The dimensions/proportions of the sides, however, are distorted whenever I do so. Any idea of why this is occurring? Could it be an issue with my CPS?

[image]

The purple square would be the original square, whereas the yellow polygon is the rotated form.

Any suggestions on how I would keep the "square" dimensions of the original shape?